# Singleton Service classes in c++

Tags: c#, c++, dependency-injection, prism, mef

Coming from a .NET/C# Background and having solid exposure to PRISM, I really like the idea of having a `CompositionContainer` to get just this one instance of a class whenever it is needed.

As through the `ServiceLocator` this instance is also globally accessible this pretty much sums up to the Singleton Pattern.

Now, my current Project is in c++, and I'm at the point of deciding how to manage plugins (external dll loading and stuff like that) for the program.

In C# I'd create a PluginService, export it as shared and channel everything through that one instance (the members would basically only amount to one list, holding the plugins and a bunch of methods). In c++ obviously I don't have a `CompositionContainer` or a `ServiceLocator`.

I could probably realize a basic version of this, but whatever I imagine involves using Singletons or Global variables for that matter. The general concern about this seems to be though: DON'T EVER DO GLOBALS AND MUCH LESS SINGLETONS.

what am I to do?
(and what I'm also interested in: is Microsoft here giving us a bad example of how to code, or is this an actual case of where singletons are the right choice?)

Comment: If we could never do globals, we wouldn't have things like `std::cout`. They can't be all that bad!

Comment: ok, so that would mean: pro globals. but then: cout is an ostream which does make sense to create more than one from. I can't see any sense to multiple instances of a PluginService though...

Comment: @MarkusHütter why not? Testing, for example? Create a PluginService, run a test against it, destroy it. Then create a new PluginService and run another test against that. You can't do that with a singleton. :) -- another answer is that just because you can't see a reason for having multiple PluginServices, that doesn't mean you should make it impossible. If the *user* of the PluginService can see a use for multiple instances, why shouldn't he be able to *create* multiple instances?

Comment: @jalf I think the last hour or so I read about you arguing against singletons =) funny to see you popping up here exactly now.

Comment: well basically what you are saying is the actual case with this pattern in c#: the exported PluginService class is in itself not a singleton. You can create it as many times as you want, but you register one instance as THE instance the whole program has agreed upon to use. that's why I wrote it sums up to the Singleton. ... So I guess that favors a normally instantiable class in a global variable?

Comment: Yeah, I think that's a reasonable approach. Much better than a "true" singleton (where it is *impossible* to create multiple instances)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's really no difference between C# and C++ in terms of whether globals and singletons are "good" or "bad".

The solution you outline is equally bad (or good) in both C# and C++.

What you seem to have discovered is simply that different people have different opinions. Some C# developers like to use singletons for something like this. And some C++ programmers feel the same way.

Some C++ programmers think a singleton is a terrible idea, and... some C# programmers feel the same way. :)

Microsoft has given *many* bad examples of how to code. Never ever accept their sample code as "good practices" just because it says Microsoft on the box. What matters is the code, not the name behind it.

Now, my main beef with singletons is *not* the global aspect of them.

Like most people, I generally dislike and distrust globals, but I won't say they should *never* be used. There are situations where it's just more convenient to make something globally accessible. They're not common (and I think most people *still* overuse globals), but they exist.

But the *real* problem with singletons is that they enforce an unnecessary and often harmful constraint on your code: they prevent you from creating multiple instances of an object, as though you, when you write the class, know how it's going to be used better than the actual *user* does.

When you write a class, say, a `PluginService` as you mentioned in a comment, you certainly have some idea of how you *plan* it to be used. You probably think "an instance of it should be globally accessible (which is debatable, because many classes should *not* access the pluginservice, but let's assume that we *do* want it to be global for now). And you probably think "I can't imagine why I'd want to have two instances".

But the problem is when you take this assumption and actively *prevent* the creation of two instances.

What if, two months from now, you find a need for creating two PluginServices? If you'd taken the easy route when you wrote the class, and had not built unnecessary constraints into it, then you could *also* take the easy route *now*, and simply create two instances.

But if you took the difficult path of writing extra code to *prevent* multiple instances from being created, then you now *again* have to take the difficult path: now you have to go back and *change* your class.

Don't build limitations into your code unless you have a reason: if it makes your job easier, go ahead and do it. And if it prevents harmful misuse of the class, go ahead and do it.

But in the singleton case it does neither of those: you create extra work for yourself, in order to prevent uses that might be perfectly legitimate.

You may be interested in reading [this blog post](http://jalf.dk/singleton/) I wrote to answer the question of singletons.

But to answer the specific question of how to handle your specific situation, I would recommend one of two approaches:

- the "purist" approach would be to create a `ServiceLocator` which is *not* global. Pass it to those who need to locate services. In my experience, you'll probably find that this is much easier than it sounds. You tend to find out that it's not actually needed in as many different places as you thought it'd be. And it gives you a motivation to decouple the code, to minimize dependencies, to ensure that only those who really have a genuine *need* for the ServiceLocator get access to it. That's healthy.
- or there's the pragmatic approach: create a single global instance of the `ServiceLocator`. Anyone who needs it can use it, and there's never any doubt about how to find it -- it's global, after all. But don't make it a singleton. Let it be possible to create other instances. If you never need to create another instance, then simply don't do it. But this leaves the door open so that if you *do* end up needing another instance, you can create it.

There are many situations where you end up needing multiple instances of a class that you *thought* would only ever need one instance. Configuration/settings objects, loggers or wrappers around some piece of hardware are all things people often call out as "this should obviously be a singleton, it makes no sense to have multiple instances", and in each of these cases, they're wrong. There are many cases where you want multiple instances of just such classes.

But the most universally applicable scenario is simply: testing.

You want to ensure that your ServiceLocator *works*. So you want to test it.

If it's  singleton, that's really hard to do. A good test should run in a pristine, isolated environment, unaffected by previous tests. But a singleton lives for the duration of the application, so if you have multiple tests of the ServiceLocator, they'll all run on the same "dirty" instance, so each test might affect the state seen by the next test.

Instead, the tests should each create a new, clean ServiceLocator, so they can control exactly which state it is in. And to do that, you need to be able to *create* instances of the class.

So don't make it a singleton. :)

Comment: ok, that just amazed me... thanks for this strong opinion and your recommended two approaches

Comment: I'll wait a few days if anyone dares to say anything else, otherwise you get the accept. thanks again for that extensive answer!

Comment: The constraint that there only be one `ServiceLocator` seems to me to be fairly fundamental (at least if the semantics are conform with its name), and worthy of being enforced.  It seems to cry out to be a singleton.  And despite claims to the contrary, I've never had any problems testing singletons.  If you have problems, I'd suggest that it is a defect in your test mechanisms, and not in the singleton concept.

Comment: "Configuration/settings objects, loggers or wrappers around some piece of hardware are all things people often call out as "this should obviously be a singleton, it makes no sense to have multiple instances", and in each of these cases, they're wrong.": the people who design them as singletons disagree with you.  And experience would seem to bear them out: having two loggers, or two configurations, is a serious programming error, which you should defend against.

Comment: And with regards to the alternative approaches: neither actually works when constructors of static objects are taken into account.

Comment: Gosh yes, the people who design X as singletons *would* disagree with me when I say that X should not be a singleton. What a revelation... They would say that, wouldn't they? I pointed out a concrete problem with testing singleton classes. Please tell me how to get around it, instead of vague implications that "you're just doing it wrong"

Comment: Having two configurations makes perfect sense. For example, you have the configuration currently in use (perhaps that's a global somewhere), and then you have *another* object representing the settings that the user is currently modifying from the settings window. They're not in effect yet, and they certainly shouldn't overwrite the ones that *are* in effect until the user clicks 'apply'. But they're a a set of configuration values *exactly* like the ones currently in effect. Why should they *not* be represented as another Settings instance?

Comment: The program might even allow the user to maintain several different profiles, where each is an instance of a Settings object. Load another profile, swap out the active settings object. And it's quite common to need more than one logger.. Say, one for ad-hoc debug output, and one for structured messages intended for the user/support staff/monitoring service. Ands no, having two configurations or loggers is only a programming error if you get them mixed up. It is not an error if you *intend* to have two.

Comment: As for constructors of static objects, well, if your static objects depend on *other* static objects during initializations, then I'd say your code has some serious problems, and then *that* is what I'd fix. I certainly wouldn't try to band-aid it by making *more* objects static.

Comment: @jalf It's strange that only now that I've come back to your answer after several years of gaining more experience I can actually really appreciate it. I have had extensive exposure to dependency injection just as to testing and now get what you're saying. So I'm changing to accept your answer... (which I wonder I didn't since that's what I proclaimed ...)

Answer (score 1):

There's absolutely nothing wrong with singletons when they're
appropriate.  I have my doubts concerning `CompositionContainer` (but
I'm not sure I understand what it is actually supposed to do), but
`ServiceLocator` is the sort of thing that will generally be a singleton
in any well designed application.  Having two or more `ServiceLocator`
will result in the program not functionning as it should (because a
service will be registered in one of them, and you'll be looking it up
in another); enforcing this programatically is positive, at least if you
favor robust programming.  In addition, in C++, the singleton idiom is
used to control the order of initialization; unless you make 
`ServiceLocator` a singleton, you can't use it in the constructor of any
object with static lifetime.

While there is a small group of very vocal anti-singleton fanatics,
within the larger C++ community, you'll find that the consensus favors
singletons, in certain very restricted cases.  They're easily abused
(but then, so are templates, dynamic allocation and polymorphism), but
they do solve one particular problem very nicely, and it would be silly
to forgo them for some arbitrary dogmatic reason when they're the best
solution for the problem.

Comment: ok, just to clarify this: static member variables, just as globals are initializied before main in a non deterministic order. if one of these would depend on the `ServiceLocator` (also as a global, not as a singleton) there would be the possibility of an error, because it might not be initialized? On the other hand having `ServiceLocator` be a Singleton, which I guess would be used through a static method with a static function variable, this would work without the possibility of an error?

Comment: @MarkusHütter Objects with static lifetime and class or namespace scope and dynamic initialization are initialized in an indeterminate order before `main`.  Objects with static initialization are initialized before any dynamic initialization, and all objects with static lifetime are zero initialized before any other initialization.  Objects with block scope, static lifetime and dynamic initialization are initialized when they are first encountered during execution.  The singleton idiom capitalizes on this by forcing execution to pass through the declaration where they are initialized.